# Error handling and showing QMessageBox in the Main.cpp

Tags: qt

Can I show a kind of "instant" message box in the `main.cpp` before showing the `MainWindow.cpp`?

In the below code, I'm opening a serial port and there are two `connect` statements and then it shows the main window.
Now, I need to alert the user with a `QMessagebox` if someting goes wrong with opening serial port (and then terminate the program).

How can I do that in the `main.cpp`?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    api.openSerialPort();

    QObject::connect(api.serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &api, SLOT(readData()));
    QObject::connect(api.serial, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)),&api, SLOT(ErrorHandler(QSerialPort::SerialPortError))); // error handling

    StageOneMain w(nullptr);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen It is 5.12.0

Comment: How do you know if something goes wrong when opening the serial port? Does the open function return something? If it's through the `error()` signal, then how would it be differentiated from normal read write errors? You wouldn't want to make the program exit on any error.

Comment: In the devlopment mode, I can see error message on the Qt Creator's application output. But this is not possible if I deploy the program and run the .exe file, if something goes wrong the program simply freezes then I need to terminate through task manager. That's why I need to show the error  through a `QMessageBox` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`QSerialPort::open()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#open) returns a boolean value to indicate if successful.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSerialPort>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    QSerialPort serial_port;
    // connecting stuffs
    if (serial_port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        w.show();
    else
        QMessageBox::warning(nullptr, QObject::tr("Open serial port error"), serial_port.errorString());
    return a.exec();
}
```